# How to submit images using javascript form

Tags: javascript

I want to create a button that when clicked, loads a form with text field and also option to add attachment (just for images). when submitted, these would be sent to myself. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: I suppose my skills are not there yet, hence the question

Answer (score 1):

To create a button that when clicked, loads a form with text field please see the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="file" id="fileBtn" onchange="uploadFile()">
</body>
<script>
    function uploadFile() {
        let file = document.getElementById('fileBtn').files[0];
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("image", file);
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: formData,
            success: (res) => {
                console.log(res)
            }
        })
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you give some verbal comments to your comment as the bare code posted is difficult to comprehend for your post readers.

Comment: Thank you . Would you be able to provide more details in terms of what html code is needed here?

Comment: @shatterstar here is the complete code, sorry i just saw you update